# Is the trivial solution the unique solution to the following initial value problem?

Tags: differential-equations

This question is a duplicate one asked by myself elsewhere. But there are no answers or comments so far. The initial value problem that I am considering is: 
$$ y'' (3y+2x)^2=3(3y'-1)(9yy' + 4xy' -y), y(0)=y'(0)=0. $$
We assume that the solution $y=y(x)$ is of class $C^2$ on a small interval $(0 , \epsilon).$ This ODE comes from a characterization of certain plane curves.
It is obvious that $y=0$ is the solution. Is this the only solution to this IVP on the arbitrary small neighborhood $(0, \epsilon)$ of $x=0 (\epsilon >0)$?

Comment: This is the duplicate from << http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153916/uniqueness-of-the-trivial-solution >>.

Comment: I have no idea how can I show that the rhs divided by $(3y+2x)^2$ is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: The linearized equation can be solved in closed form, and it does not have any nontrivial solutions for which y and y' are zero at the origin. You can probably use this as the basis for a contraction argument.

Comment: I tried! But it's not an easy job.